# How to get state of the streaming source in GStreamer-Python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, camera, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to analyze and take actions depending on the current state of the streaming source in gstreamer. I have a basic script to create pipeline elements, linking them and eventually see the live IP camera stream on my screen. However, most of the IP cameras seems to stop streaming the video at some point. The camera IP is accessible but RTSP drops the connection or displaying an all-black screen. I want to detect when the stream gets dropped and create a controlling interval to reconnect to the stream again. I'm already listening some bus messages at runtime but it doesn't seem like any of them is providing what I need.

It would be great to have some ideas on how to check the state of the stream at any given time.

Here is a basic blocks from my code:

```
def on_src_pad_added(src, new_pad, depayer):
    sink_pad = depayer.get_static_pad("sink")

    if(sink_pad.is_linked()):
        print("We are already linked. Ignoring.")
        return

    # check the new pad's type
    new_pad_caps = new_pad.get_current_caps()
    new_pad_struct = new_pad_caps.get_structure(0)
    new_pad_type = new_pad_struct.get_name()

    ret = new_pad.link(sink_pad)
    return

def gst_to_opencv(sample):
    buf = sample.get_buffer()
    caps = sample.get_caps()

    arr = np.ndarray(
        (caps.get_structure(0).get_value('height'),
         caps.get_structure(0).get_value('width'),
         3),
        buffer=buf.extract_dup(0, buf.get_size()),
        dtype=np.uint8)
    return arr

def new_buffer(sink, data):
    global image_arr
    sample = sink.emit("pull-sample")
    arr = gst_to_opencv(sample)
    image_arr = arr
    return Gst.FlowReturn.OK
```

After these callbacks I'm constructing my pipeline:

```
def main():
    # Standard GStreamer initialization
    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)

    # Create gstreamer elements
    # Create Pipeline element that will form a connection of other elements
    print("Creating Pipeline \n ")
    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

    if not pipeline:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Pipeline \n")

    # Source element for reading from the file
    print("Creating Source \n ")
    source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtspsrc", "rtsp-cam-source")
    if not source:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Source \n")

    depay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtph264depay", "rtp-depay")
    if not depay:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create videoconvert \n")

    parser = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse", "h264-parser")
    if not parser:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create videoconvert \n")

    decoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("avdec_h264", "h264-decoder")
    if not decoder:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create videoconvert \n")
...

Set plugin properties...
Add plugins to the pipeline...
Link plugins...
...
```

Lastly, my live streaming and message listening block is as follows:

```
...
# start play back and listen to events
    print("Starting pipeline \n")
    ret = pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
        print("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.")
        exit(-1)

    # create an event loop and feed gstreamer bus mesages to it
    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    
    # Parse message
    while True:
        pipe_state = pipeline.get_state(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
        print(pipe_state.state)

        message = bus.timed_pop_filtered(10000, Gst.MessageType.ANY)
        if image_arr is not None:   
            cv2.imshow("Receive Image from Pipeline Buffer", image_arr)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break
        if message:
            if message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
                err, debug = message.parse_error()
                print(("Error received from element %s: %s" % (
                    message.src.get_name(), err)))
                print(("Debugging information: %s" % debug))
                break
            elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
                print("End-Of-Stream reached.")
                break
            elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.STATE_CHANGED:
                if isinstance(message.src, Gst.Pipeline):
                    old_state, new_state, pending_state = message.parse_state_changed()
                    print(("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s." %
                        (old_state.value_nick, new_state.value_nick)))
            else:
                # print(message.type)
                continue

    # cleanup
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
```

Comment: I think you'll need to add some code to make it possible to give a concrete answer. But at a high level I'd recommend adding probes (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/design/probes.html?gi-language=python) to your code if you haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Please see my question post again. I have just added my basic code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give an straight answer without some code, but it should be possible to get the state of a given pipeline with the gst-python bindings. For example, something like:

```
pipeline.get_state(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
```

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/main/subprojects/gst-python/examples/record_sound.py#L89

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added my code to the question. I also tried to see if I can catch anything by printing `pipe_state.state` when I plugged off my IP camera but it doesn't print anything other than `PLAYING`

Comment: In general the state of the source element (rtspsrc) should propagate through the pipeline, so checking the state of the pipeline instead of the element should reflect that. However there could be some settings in the rtspsrc element that could cause the state to not change even if you disconnect the IP cameras. For example are you setting the "tcp-timeout", "tcp-timeout", "message-forward" properties in rtspsrc?

Comment: Another option you have is to check the state of the "rtspsrc" element itself instead of the pipeline.

Comment: I've set the following parameters for the `rtspsrc` plugin: `message-forward` to `true`, `timeout` to `0`, `tcp-timeout` to `0`, `udp-reconnect` to 0 and `retry` to `0`. But still when I disconnect the cameras, I can not get any info about the current state of pipeline or source element.

Comment: Another option you have is to extend the bus watch parsing logic, since you already have a bus watch you could try to add a new case in the parsing logic to check for warning messages. The rtspsrc should generate a message of type GST_MESSAGE_WARNING when the sender stops streaming for some reason.